# Get bash to stop running after x seconds

Tags: bash, location, applescript

## So I have this Applescript:

```
on run{}
    set myPath to path to me as text
    set x to the length of myPath
    set myPath to characters 13 thru x of myPath as string --Removes "Macintosh HD:" from the front of the file path
    set myPath to my fileAdapt(myPath)
    set lat to do shell script myPath & " -f \"{LAT}\"" --See comments below the script
    set lon to do shell script myPath & " -f \"{LON}\""
end run

on fileAdapt(myPath)
    set x to the length of myPath
    set myPath1 to ""
    repeat with i from 1 to x
        if character i of myPath is ":" then
            set myPath1 to myPath1 & "/"
        else if character i of myPath is " " then
            set myPath1 to myPath1 & "\\ "
        else
            set myPath1 to myPath1 & (character i of myPath)
        end if
    end repeat
    set myPath1 to myPath1 & "Contents/Resources/LocateMe" as string --See comments below the script
    return myPath1
end fileAdapt
```

where [LocateMe](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/locateme/) is a bash script that can get a user's latitude and longitude, among other statistics, using the `-f` command.

## The Issue

Now, on first run, the program asks for permission to get the user's location. If the user presses "OK," then all is good. But if the user presses "Cancel," we've got issues.

As I describe over on SuperUser regarding [deleting applications from Location Services](https://superuser.com/questions/526183/remove-applications-from-location-services-in-security-privacy-on-mac-os-x-10?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1901260_526183), LocateMe seems to continue running in the background until Location Services are turned back on. In the meantime, my Applescript just hangs until the bash script finishes loading, or until I force-quit the application (or Script Editor, whatever I'm running it in). Obviously, this is not a desirable behavior.

To make matters worse, once the application has asked for Location Services permission, it never asks again; the user has to manually go to System Preferences and tick the box themselves (or [get a script to do it for him](https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/5173-request-location-services-toggle/)). What this means is that on a *second* run of this script, the user would have absolutely no way of knowing why the script is hanging.

My first attempt at dealing with this was to stuff LocateMe inside a `try` statement, but, as per my conclusion above, that wouldn't do anything; since LocateMe continues running until it gets access to the user's location, the Applescript never reaches the `on error` line.

## My Question

I would like to know if there is a way to call LocateMe from within some sort of statement, be it an Applescript or a bash script or some other language that can be run from within an Applescript, that sets a time limit; if the time limit is not reached, LocateMe will be terminated, and the Applescript will display an error message to the user, explaining that location services must be turned on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to introduce timeout for shell scripting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting#43346)

Comment: @match It looks promising. In practice, how would I implement that?

Comment: If you have `timeout` available, simply run `timeout -k 10 /path/to/LocateMe` (where 10 is the number of seconds before timeout. Otherwise either call that `expect` command directly, replacing `$command` with LocateMe, or copy that function into your `.bashrc` so that the function `timeout` is available in bash, and call that.

Comment: @match And I leave `$time` like that, or would I similarly replace that with however many seconds(?) until it times out? Or is that handled by the `if` statement? (Yes, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing when it comes to bash.)

Comment: That expect example is defining a `bash function` - when you call functions with arguments, they get put into variables called `$1`, `$2` etc. So for `timeout 10 foo` `$1` would be `10` and `$2` would be `foo`. If you copy it 'as-is' into your `.bashrc` you can use it in the same way as the `timeout` command. Alternatively, just copy the `expect` line into your script, and replace all the variables with hard-coded values (time, command etc).

Comment: @match Sounds good. Do you want to post all of that as an answer?

Comment: Why go through so much rigmarole!? The following line of _code_ replaces all of the _code_ you have getting you to the `do shell script` _command_: `set LocateMe to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to me as string) & "Contents/Resources/LocateMe")` - You could then use `set cmdArg to "-f \"{LAT}, {LON}\""` - Followed by `set LatLon to do shell script LocateMe & space & cmdArg` - and then `set lat to word 1 of LatLon` and `set lon to word 2 of LatLon` - These 5 lines of _code_ replace the 23 lines of _code_ you've shown. :)

Comment: @user3439894 Well, that's interesting. I'll test that one out. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user3439894 I had to modify that last line to `set lon to -((word 2 of LatLon) as number)`, as it kept giving me a positive (east) longitude when I'm in the western (negative) hemisphere. But otherwise that works flawlessly, thanks!

Comment: I don't have LocateMe installed and could not test, so was going off the top of my head with the _suggested code_. As usual, modify to meet your needs. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible duplicate of [How to introduce timeout for shell scripting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting#43346)

If you have timeout available, simply run `timeout -k 10 Contents/Resources/LocateMe` (where 10 is the number of seconds before timeout.

Otherwise either call that expect command directly, replacing $command with `Contents/Resources/LocateMe`, or copy that function into your .bashrc so that the function timeout is available in bash, and call that.

That expect example is defining a bash function - when you call functions with arguments, they get put into variables called `$1`, `$2` etc. So for `timeout 10 foo`,  `$1` would be `10` and `$2` would be `foo`. If you copy it 'as-is' into your `.bashrc` you can use it in the same way as the `timeout` command suggested above. Alternatively, just copy the expect line out of the function into your script, and replace all the variables with hard-coded values (time, command etc).

Comment: Okay, so I'm clearly not getting something, because this isn't working. I'm supposed to save the `.command` file in the same folder as the `LocateMe` executable, then set the filepath to that folder, and finally run the `timeout` bash using `do shell script` and call `LocateMe` from `timeout`? That is to say, use user3439894's code from the comments to the OP, but sub in `timeout.sh` for `LocateMe` in the first line, and modify line 3 appropriately?

Comment: Whenever I try calling that script I keep getting access denied, and I'd rather not `sudo` my way through this if it's avoidable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6qA4.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Cln.png

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the purpose of the `.bashrc` file and how bash functions work. You should read up on these to understand what's happening here. Its not directly important, but I also think that any script you do try to run needs `execute` permission as well

Comment: For what I intend to do with this app I'd rather call the entire thing in the script itself rather than to stick the command into the `.bashrc`. Can I not just say `do shell script [filename] username "user" password "pass" with administrator privileges`? Because clearly that's not working.